# Cordova iOS project: xCode 9 missing some entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, xcode9

The xCode project I'm working on is a hybrid app generated by Cordova/Ionic with:

```
cordova build ios
```

In my xCode 9, when I go to "Targets" → "General" Tab → "Signing (Release)" section I can see that my Provisioning Profile has 12 entitlements, as you can see in the following image:

[image: 12 entitlements from general tab]

Note that "aps-environment" is included.

Now, after archive process ("Product" → "Archive", click in the "Export..." button and choose "App Store" option) and selecting the same provisioning profile I can see the same 12 entitlements (What is great), as you can see in the next pic.

[image: 12 entitlements after archieve process]

But now, after I click in the "Next" button I can see only 7 entitlements in the summary. Note that "aps-environment" is not present:

[image: 7 entitlements from summary]

As a consequence my I'm receiving an e-mail message from App Store team saying that my .IPA is "Missing Push Notification Entitlement". The capability "Push Notifications" is enabled in the "Capabilities" tab.

I have tried reinstalling my provisioning profile, but not worked.

How can I fix it? Am I forgetting something?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved.**

For some reason `cordova build ios` is generating the native project with the value of the key "Code Signing Entitlements" pointing to the wrong file location.

So in the tab "Build settings", "Signing" section I changed the value `<ProjectName>/Resources/value <ProjectName>.entitlements` to value `<ProjectName>/value <ProjectName>.entitlements` for the key "Code Signing Entitlements" and all worked.

[image: Fix file location]

Comment: I also had this problem and solved it with the same solution. Will the `Code Signing Entitlements` setting be preserved if I do `cordova build ios` again?

Comment: Hello @CharlieAng. Yes, it will be preserved.